# AngularJS Request to ExpressJS via localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I created a Web Application using AngularJS x ExpressJS where GET "/" of my `app.js` renders the `index.html` of the application.

For example, I have GET `/test-data` on my `app.js` and trying to fetch those test data from AngularJS via `localhost:port/test-data`. While this is working on my test environment, I always had to alter the request URL on production to production's REST.

Is there any way that I can prevent the problem stated above editing the URL during deployment?

Sample codes:

**(app.js)**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
var port = 3000;
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/test-data", function(req, res, next) {
    var returnValue = [
        {
            username : "MAIK",
            fullname : "Michael"
        },
        {
            username : "CLARK",
            fullname : "Clark"
        },
        {
            username : "ROLLY",
            fullname : "Roland"
        },
        {
            username : "FLOYDIE",
            fullname : "Floyd"
        },
        {
            username : "ZOE",
            fullname : "Zoe"
        }
    ];

    res.send(returnValue);

});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening to port " + port + "...");
});
```

**(MySampleService.js)**

```
.service("MySampleService", function($http) {

    this.sampleURL = "localhost:3000";    

    this.getTestData= function(){
        return $http
        (
            {
                method : "GET",
                url : "http://" + this.sampleURL + "/test-data
            }
        );
    };
});
```

Comment: You are hardcoding the url in your service here, ` this.sampleURL = "localhost:3000";`

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary Is there any way that I can send an HTTP request declaring the host URL?

Comment: have a switch condition for your dev, test and prod environments which returns the host name for those three envs. Based on the env value that you get from the switch condition, you would stitch the host url or any of the urls needed in your service. However you can use "location.hostname" to get the host name.

Comment: the first condition is an ideal way of doing things, but the second one works too nevertheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your URL, simply use `/test-data`. The request automatically knows to use the same port the app is hosted on.

Comment: It does! I tried $location.host() + ":" + $location.port() after reading the comments. But I think this is the simplest way to deal with this.